# My custom AS3 image loading classes are loading images twice...not intended behavior

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance

I have these two classes:

Each one is linked to a symbol in the library.
dynamic_single_image and dynamic_image, respectively.

I drag an instance of dynamic_image onto my timeline...and based on the name of the movieclip instance...I have code inloadMyImage to load an image file name and its associated alternate image.

Ideally what happens is that DynamicImage's loadMyImage is called (loads alt image)...it in turn calls super.loadMyImage (loads english image). Two image files should be loaded.

HOWEVER, this pair of images is LOADED TWICE...see trace statements below.

I feel like even though my movieclip instance is of DynamicImage...the super's constructor is called first and then DyanmicImage's constructor is called!

```
public class DynamicSingleImage extends Sprite
{
    var eLoader:Loader; //for english image

    public function DynamicSingleImage()
    {
        trace("DynamicSingleImage...for: " + this.name);
        loadMyImage();          
    }

    public function loadMyImage () :void 
    {
      ...

      trace( "always load ENGLISH file :" + engFilename );

      ...
    }
  }




public class DynamicImage extends DynamicSingleImage
{
    var aLoader:Loader; //for alternate language image

    public function DynamicImage()
    {
        trace("DynamicImage for: " + this.name);
        this.loadMyImage();

    }

    override public function loadMyImage () :void 
    {
        trace("============= START ========================");
        trace("loading images for mc: " + this.name);

                    ...

        super.loadMyImage(); //first call the super to load the English version
                trace( "load image for alternate language..." + altFilename

                    ...

        trace("============= END ========================");
            }
```

This is the traced output:

```
DynamicSingleImage...for: eel_hotspot_content_mc
============= START ========================
loading images for mc: eel_hotspot_content_mc
always load ENGLISH file :eel_hotspot_content.jpg
load image for alternate language...eel_hotspot_content_alt.jpg
============= END ========================
DynamicImage for: eel_hotspot_content_mc
============= START ========================
loading images for mc: eel_hotspot_content_mc
always load ENGLISH file :eel_hotspot_content.jpg
load image for alternate language...eel_hotspot_content_alt.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

The super constructor is indeed called first when a specific call to it isn't present in the extended constructor. I think the simplest solution would be to force the constructor to be called second and have a flag that is checked to see if the image has already been loaded once. See below:

```
public class DynamicSingleImage extends Sprite
{
    var eLoader:Loader; //for english image
    var loaded:Boolean;

    public function DynamicSingleImage()
    {
        trace("DynamicSingleImage...for: " + this.name);

        if (!loaded)
            loadMyImage();          
    }

    public function loadMyImage () :void 
    {
      ...

      trace( "always load ENGLISH file :" + engFilename );

      loaded = true;

      ...
    }
  }




public class DynamicImage extends DynamicSingleImage
{
    var aLoader:Loader; //for alternate language image

    public function DynamicImage()
    {
        trace("DynamicImage for: " + this.name);
        this.loadMyImage();

        super();

    }

    override public function loadMyImage () :void 
    {
        trace("============= START ========================");
        trace("loading images for mc: " + this.name);

                    ...

        super.loadMyImage(); //first call the super to load the English version
                trace( "load image for alternate language..." + altFilename

                    ...

        trace("============= END ========================");
            }
```

Comment: +1 for the info that the super construtor is always called from the sub class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Since the super constructor is called automatically, I took out the loadMyImage from my sub class's constructor.

That was it. Now this is what happens...

1. The instance of my movieclip on stage instantiates DynamicImage
2. DynamicImage's constructor automatically calls the super constructor
3. The super constructor calls the OVERRIDDEN loadMyImage in my subclass!!!
4. My sub class's loadMyImage calls super.loadMyImage

Now all is well. The 'english' image loads from super.loadMyImage...the 'alt' image loads in the sub class's loadMyImage.